# Laravel - Stop at error (especially when at View)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

Occaisionally I get an error in a View template that is hard to debug since instead of just stopping at the error, Laravel redirects to the 'Whoops' error page. Unfortunately the stacktrace there is rarely helpful as it corresponds to code in the internal framework and nothing to do with my code. However, if the page was to just die where the fatal error occured as normal PHP code would, it would be a lot easier to diagnose the issue. Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: Did you check the logs ? Is your app `APP_DEBUG` set to true ?

Comment: The best way would be to check the logs in `storage/logs/laravel.log` as @RajaKhoury suggested. If you would post the actual error you're getting or a screen grab, we might offer some help.

Comment: Use try and catch in case sensitive places (i sugest to create some exception class for more specific debug report), search places, where data can miss, and set  `App::error(function(Exception $exception)
{
    Log::error($exception);
});`